# Delete portion of Isearch string that does not match, or last char if complete match

Tags: isearch, deletion

I have the following

```el
(defun isearch-del-fail-or-char ()
  "Delete failed isearch text, or if there is none, a single character."
  (interactive)
  (if (isearch-fail-pos)
      (delete-region (isearch-fail-pos) (point))
    (isearch-del-char)))

(define-key isearch-mode-map (kbd "DEL") 'isearch-del-fail-or-char)
```

The purpose of the code is to make `delete` in isearch delete the entire failed string (or if there is no failed string just a single character).

However, `delete-region` is deleting text from the buffer `isearch` is searching in, not the isearch buffer itself.

What is the proper way to do this? Critique on the rest of my emacs lisp style is also welcome :)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Ah yes.  Isearch reads the keys you type, looks them up in `isearch-mode-map`, and invokes them **in the current buffer**.

Isearch does **not**, in spite of appearances, use the minibuffer.  It uses the echo area. That is, what you see there is actually *output* messages, including echoes of the characters you type.

This should do what you ask:

```el
(defun mydelete ()
  "Delete the failed portion of the search string, or the last char if successful."
  (interactive)
  (with-isearch-suspended
      (setq isearch-new-string
            (substring
             isearch-string 0 (or (isearch-fail-pos) (1- (length isearch-string))))
            isearch-new-message
            (mapconcat 'isearch-text-char-description isearch-new-string ""))))

(define-key isearch-mode-map (kbd "DEL") 'mydelete)
```

(BTW, your question says the `delete` character, but you wrote `DEL`, which is the backspace character.)

---

As @Malabarba points out in a comment, when you set the new search string to **`""`** (empty string), `with-isearch-suspended` resumes by searching for the last search string, instead starting with an empty search string.

This is a "*feature*" of `with-isearch-suspended`, in general.  But because you sometimes might really want to empty the search string for resumption, 
in the version of `with-isearch-suspended` in [isearch+.el](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/download/isearch%2b.el) I've added variable **`isearchp-if-empty-prefer-resuming-with-last`**, to control this.  If you bind that to `nil` and you set `isearch-new-string` to `""` then search resumes with an empty search string.

So with [**Isearch+**](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/IsearchPlus) you can do what you want with this definition:

```el
(defun mydelete ()
  "Delete the failed portion of the search string, or the last char if successful."
  (interactive)
  (let ((isearchp-if-empty-prefer-resuming-with-last  nil))
    (with-isearch-suspended
        (setq isearch-new-string
              (substring
               isearch-string 0 (or (isearch-fail-pos) (1- (length isearch-string))))
              isearch-new-message
              (mapconcat 'isearch-text-char-description isearch-new-string "")))))
```

I notice too now that Emacs 24.4 introduced a regression, which I've filed [Emacs bug #20466](http://debbugs.gnu.org/cgi/bugreport.cgi?bug=20466) for, which means that binding `DEL` in `isearch-mode-map` is not sufficient.  They added a separate binding for `<backspace>`, in addition to one for `DEL`.  That means that `<backspace>` no longer gets translated to `DEL`, for Isearch (but it does still get so translated for Emacs generally).

So if you want the Backspace key to do what you asked in Emacs 24.4 or later then you cannot just bind `DEL` to `mydelete`.  You need to bind `<backspace>` to `mydelete`.  Dumb, AFAICT, mais *on n'arrete pas le progres*...

---

I've added a similar command to [**Isearch+**](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/IsearchPlus) and bound it to **`C-M-l`** (the same key used to remove a completion mismatch in [**Icicles**](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Icicles)).

Be aware too that `C-g` in Isearch will also, when there is a mismatch, remove the mismatched text.  (But `C-g` also has an effect when search is successful.)

---

I should have mentioned that **Isearch+** has also had an optional behavior along similar lines for quite a while now. **`M-k`** during Isearch toggles among 3 behaviors, which are controlled by the value of option **`isearchp-drop-mismatch`**:

- `replace-last` - Your current input replaces the last mismatched
  text.  You can always see your last input, even
  if it is a mismatch.  And it is available for
  editing using `M-e`.
- `nil` - Your current input is appended, even if the
  previous input has a mismatched portion.
- anything else  - Your current input is ignored (removed) if it
  causes a mismatch.  The search string always has successful matches.

Comment: BTW, I've thought about adding a similar command to [**Isearch+**](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/IsearchPlus) ever since I added highlighting of the failed portion (years ago, before I added it to GNU Emacs), but I never got around to it. I've [done that now](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/IsearchPlus#isearchp-remove-failed-part). (I didn't include deletion of a character, however. The command I added is a no-op if there is no failed portion.)

Comment: I'm on OS X. I meant backwards delete.

Comment: The isearch+ replace-last behavior looks pretty nice. Is any way to make it not ring the bell every time the search fails, though?

Comment: Also it's very janky with `replace-last`, because it prints "I-search:" and "Failing I-search" immediately after one another.

Comment: Now that I play with it, it looks like the best behavior is this code *and* `replace-last`. That way, I can see the failing string, but pressing delete (or backspace, whatever) to delete it, as my reflexes are wont to do, still works.

Comment: I uploaded a new version of [`isearch+.el`](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/download/isearch%2b.el). It (a) fixes automatic mismatch removal so that wraparound works OK. And it adds an option, **`isearchp-ring-bell-function`**, which you can use to suppress the bell during search.

Comment: I don't see the `isearchp-ring-bell-function` in the source you linked to.

Comment: Well, it's there. Perhaps you need to clear your browser cache or something.

Comment: Hi Drew, I have a bug in your `mydelete` function. If you search for a single character, and then delete this character, the isearch prompt will get populated with the previous search.

Comment: Malabarba, interesting. I took a shot at the bug and ended up with [this](https://gist.github.com/johnmastro/508fb22a2b4e1ce754e0). Mostly cargo-culted from `isearch-del-char` and Drew's answer but it seems to work as intended. The `with-isearch-suspended` macro was the culprit.

Comment: @Malabarba & jbm: See my edit about improving `with-isearch-suspended` in this regard for [Isearch+](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/IsearchPlus).

Comment: Coming back to this, the version with `isearchp-if-empty-prefer-resuming-with-last` doesn't seem to work, but the function in @jbm's gist does.

Comment: @asmeurer: Sorry, but "*doesn't seem to work*" means nothing to me. And I don't even know just what you mean by "*the version with...*" (what value of that variable, etc.). Please give a recipe, specifying what you see and what you expected to see instead. You can send this to me by email, if you like: `M-x customize-group isearch-plus`, then click link `Send Bug Report`. Thx.

Comment: @Drew I'm referring to the code you wrote in this answer.

Comment: @asmeurer: *Recipe, please.* It works for me. (Note that you might need to use `(kbd "<backspace>")` instead of `(kbd "DEL")`.) But both jbm's gist and the code above work for me. Please be specific about what you are doing, and why you think it "*doesn't seem to work*".

Comment: @Drew, this is the code I have in my .emacs https://gist.github.com/asmeurer/e82697ba2f7c16f47e87. I should look *very* familiar. When I do an isearch with it and delete the last character, it goes back to the previous search. When I replace `mydelete` with `isearch-delete-something` from @jbm's gist and do the same thing, it does what I want (doesn't revert to a previous search).

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't thinking. I think I understand now, and I think it is fixed. Please try the latest [`isearch+.el`](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/download/isearch%2b.el). `C-<backspace>` is bound to a command that I think does what you want. You might want to bind that command to `<backspace>` instead. Let me know what you think.

Comment: @Drew Hi, Drew! Would there be any way to behave like the default isearch (jump back to previous states) but if deleting a failed input, delete it like in you answer? By that I mean if I go start of the scratch buffer with default `initial-scratch-message` and search for "isiqqq" then when I press DEL the first time delete the failed "qqq" part and if press DEL next time behave like usual (jump back from "visit" to "This")?

Comment: @Drew I figured it out the solution was simple: `(while (progn (isearch-delete-char) (isearch-fail-pos)))`